# from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth > cannot import name 'mtls' from 'google.auth.transport

Tags: python, pydrive

I am trying to read csv from google drive.
when I run those lines

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
```

it says:

cannot import name 'mtls' from 'google.auth.transport  (C:\Users\RAFI\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\auth\transport_*init*_.py)

Answer (score 0):

Installing mtls and googletrans modules solved this for me.

```
pip install mtls
pip install googletrans
```